# Impact of power cuts on electricity consumption

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to work out which types of property are most affected by rolling blackouts (ie. South Africa has Load Shedding where our power utility shuts down power when demand exceeds supply). I have collated the load shedding information into MegaWatts shed per month:

| Year Month | MegaWatts |
| --- | --- |
| 201502 | 28400.0 |
| 201503 | 9900.0 |
| 201504 | 70900.0 |
| 201505 | 57700.0 |
| 201506 | 15400.0 |
| 201507 | 14400.0 |
| ...... | ...... |
| 202207 | 1216200.0 |
| 202208 | 22200.0 |
| 202209 | 1983600.0 |
| 202210 | 1417000.0 |
| 202211 | 26000.0 |

This is a sample of the information available for electricity consumption.

| Year Month | Property Type | Total Consumption | No. Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201807 | Agricultural | 112217.50 | 46 |
| 201807 | Business | 3281828.70 | 1155 |
| 201807 | Government | 117490.40 | 56 |
| 201807 | Industry | 1431048.20 | 194 |
| 201807 | Municipal | 1084101.90 | 1381 |
| 201807 | Residential | 5355781.20 | 13145 |
| 201808 | Agricultural | 111931.40 | 46 |
| 202104 | Industry | 507556.60 | 129 |
| 202104 | Municipal | 600801.50 | 608 |
| 202104 | Residential | 3174809.10 | 7871 |
| 202105 | Agricultural | 28465.00 | 17 |
| 202105 | Business | 1286016.80 | 850 |
| 202105 | Government | 87199.40 | 37 |
| 202105 | Industry | 409162.00 | 132 |

When I produce a graph of Average Monthly Consumption (all property types) and MegaWatts of load shedding, I get the following:[image]

I am trying a Paired t-test for consecutive months but am worried about natural fluctuations in electricity consumption due to seasonality. I have looked into Interrupted Time Series analysis but am not at all familiar with this methodology.

Any advice on a good approach for this?

Comment: What do you mean by `which types of property are most affected by rolling blackouts`, how are you measuring this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are different Property Types in the consumption data (eg. Residential, Agricultural etc). I want to test how load shedding affects each property type. eg. Is Residential property affected more than Agricultural property.

It seems certain properties, like residential and business, have battery backups which then recharge once the power is restored, thus requiring electricity to recharge the batteries therefore perhaps a lower affect than properties that don't have battery backups.

I am sourcing socio-economic data so I will be able to test against those parameters in future

Comment: Do you have data about who has batteries, how much and when they are using them? If you don't then how can you tell what's what?

Comment: No I don't have data on battery usage, that was just an example. There may be other reasons like access to gas cookers etc. The purpose of my analysis is to find out if there is a segment of the population that is less affected by load shedding and only then to find out why they are less affected.

Comment: And how will you measure this, the effect of load shedding on the population?

Comment: By looking at the consumption of electricity in months that have load shedding and comparing consumption of electricity to months that don't have load shedding

Comment: I see, so you are trying to compare consumption within the various types when there was shedding vs. no shedding, to check if there was a difference in consumption? To get back to your battery example, is battery usage (or some other usage) also included in the total consumption?